# PC内のローカルな画像ファイルを送信してComputer Vision APIで解析したい

Tags: java, api, http, azure

今の段階では、ネット上に転がってる画像のURLから画像を解析することはできています。
ローカルな画像（ｐｃ内の画像）をpost（？）して解析するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
PC内の画像のパスを入力しても無理でした（当たり前ですが）
HTTP Client　でリクエストボディに画像のバイナリを書きこんでpostすればいいらしいというところまでは何となくわかりましたがその方法は全く分かりません。
プログラミングやHTTP通信系の知識はあまりない大学生です。
どなたかよろしくお願いします。

```
package;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class newIoT {

    // **********************************************
    // *** Update or verify the following values. ***
    // **********************************************

    // Replace <Subscription Key> with your valid subscription key.
    private static final String subscriptionKey = "**********************";

    // You must use the same region in your REST call as you used to get your
    // subscription keys. For example, if you got your subscription keys from
    // westus, replace "westcentralus" in the URI below with "westus".
    //
    // Free trial subscription keys are generated in the westcentralus region. If you
    // use a free trial subscription key, you shouldn't need to change this region.
    private static final String uriBase =
            "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/analyze";

    //private static final String imageToAnalyze =
            //"https://www.fashion-press.net/img/news/38545/Ej4.jpg";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("タグ、文章を取得したい画像URLを入力");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ImageURL = sc.next();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        try {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(uriBase);

            // Request parameters. All of them are optional.
            builder.setParameter("visualFeatures", "Categories,Description,Color");
            builder.setParameter("language", "en");

            // Prepare the URI for the REST API call.
            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);

            // Request headers.
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            // Request body.
            StringEntity requestEntity =
                    new StringEntity("{\"url\":\"" + ImageURL + "\"}");
            request.setEntity(requestEntity);

            // Make the REST API call and get the response entity.
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: コードが途中で途切れているように見えますがお間違えないですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここに書いてるように、適切なContentTypeを指定してFileEntityを使えばよいかと思います。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463736/how-to-send-a-local-image-instead-of-url-to-microsoft-computer-vision-api-using

```
// Request headers.
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

// Request body.
File file = new File(imagePath);
FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file);
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```